# How add the straight line between bubbles in highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How add the straight line between bubbles in highchart

for examples pls refer the screen chart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXwGr.jpg)

I am try the following coding but I don't have luck. Could you pls help for this

```
function (chart) {             
               for(i=0; i<= 1; i++){                
                       var val = ((i == 0)? 0 : (i + 1));

                       var point = chart.series[0].points[val];  

                       var point1 = chart.series[0].points[(val + 1)];

                       console.log( val +"  nnnnnnnnnnnnnn ", point , point1);            

                       chart.renderer.path(['M', point.plotX + 140  , point.plotY, 'H', point1.plotX + 140])
                       .attr({
                         'stroke-width': 2,
                         stroke: 'red',
                         id: 'vert'
                       }).add();

               }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with highcharts, your best option is to try to use their existing (extensive) API capabilities for customizing the series.

To get a line between the bubles in a series you need to set the lineWidth property of the series to be more then 0.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.bubble.lineWidth

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            lineWidth:1
//    ... other settings here ...
        }
    }
```

Pair-wise connection of the bubbles may be achieved by adding a separate series per each pair.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I would suggest not using series per pair for many points - the performance will be decreased. Instead, it is possible to separate bubbles with nulls points. http://jsfiddle.net/xze6a2wq/

Comment: Thanks for your comments its working you save my time

Comment: Is there a way to get the lines to render behind the circles? Having the lines on top of the circles is hideous if your circles are a different color than the lines.

Comment: @AlecK interesting question. I tried to set opacity to 1, but it didn't help. Perhaps a good idea to create a separate question on this topic.